# active admin installing issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I am installing active admin in rails by this command

```
rails g active_admin:install
```

but get this error

```
aftab@Aftab-Pc:~/railscms$ rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
/home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f28a4e0fb315/lib/active_admin/application.rb:37:in `method_missing': undefined method `register_javascript' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x0055a2df926508>
Did you mean?  register_page (NoMethodError)
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/active_admin_editor-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/editor/engine.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/active_admin_editor-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/editor/engine.rb:16:in `tap'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/active_admin_editor-1.1.0/lib/active_admin/editor/engine.rb:16:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  from /home/aftab/railscms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
  from /home/aftab/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top
```

Comment: Try again with the latest version from Github or rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

register_javascript was removed from the install template at the end of July, see [activeadmin#5216](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5216).  You appear to be trying to add active_admin_editor, which has not been updated in years.  There are some other WISIWYG plugins listed at on the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins).